# How to generate link with image using javascript on a web site?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to generate this construction on a web site using javascript: `<a href="URL"><img src="IMG_URL"></a>` and as I understand there are 3 steps:

1. On site load  javascript sending request (ajax?) to remote server URL (http://website.com/data.php)
2. As response from remote server he got two values (URL, IMG_URL)
3. Then javascript creates a link `<a href="URL"><img src="IMG_URL"></a>` and put it on web site (for examle in  ?)

The idea is to show different banners on a web site from remote banner server. It's like adsense does I think but without iframe.

Comment: Whatever the server replies to the ajax requst, the javascript will show. What's your question?

Comment: The question was how to use javascript to generate link from received values, dbucki answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

response data.php from server as json

```
{
     "url":"http://www.example.com",
     "url_img":"http://www.example.com/image.jpg"
}
```

and JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/data.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res) {
             var anchor = '<a href="'+res.url+'"><img src="'+res.url_img+'" alt=""></a>';
             $('body').append(anchor);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I've added this but nothing on the page. I've set url to real URL where json data provided, and put js code on the page, but nothing happens. Maybe I've missed something how to show result on the page?

Comment: In google console I see this: GET http://example.com/data.php net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: Okey, this is my browser plugin adblock. Turned it off solved this. Everything works perfect!